# How to design parts of an Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: c#, syntax, tree, abstract

I am writing a C# interpreter from scratch for the learning experience, and so far everything has gone smoothly. I have a fully functional C# lexer that outputs all sorts of tokens to the parser. I know how I am going to parse the tokens, but I'm not sure how I should structure my AST (abstract syntax tree).

For example, if I have a simple code fragment:

```
using System.Xml;
```

what would the tree look like when parsed?

Like this?

```
UsingDirective
   Identifier(System)
      Identifier(Xml)
```

or like this?

```
UsingDirective
   Identifier(System)
   Identifier(Xml)
```

If I could get some suggestions and/or examples as to how I could structure things like identifiers with dots in them, if/else if/else statements, variable declaration/assignment combined in one statement (int i = 0;), function definitions, etc. that would be helpful. I just need to get a better idea of how to structure the tree and I can figure out the rest myself. Thanks.

Comment: That's going to be a long learning experience, if you want to implement all of C# :-)

Comment: Well I'm leaving out the majority of the class library. I'm basically just implementing what needs to be implemented for basic class/function definitions, variable creation/usage, and function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a couple of parsers in the past, and I would generally go for something like this:

```
UsingDirective
   IdentifierList
     Identifier (LeftNode) (System)
     Identifier (RightNode) (Xml)
```

In case of this `using System.Collections.Generic`

```
UsingDirective
   IdentifierList
       IdentifierList (LeftNode)
           Identifier (LeftNode) (System)
           Identifier (RightNode) (Collections)
       Identifier (RightNode) (Generic)
```

Unlike Roslyn, I prefer keeping my ASTs light by not including tokens such as semi-colon, the `using` keyword etc since the compiler has no need for them.

Parsers I've written specifically for IDEs look different - they carry all this extra stuff along with more information such as line and column numbers.

Comment: Why did you make your `IdentifierList` have only two children? Why not have a single `IdentifierList` with as many children as necessary?

Comment: Yeah I think a single IdentifierList with unlimited children would be better. In any case, thanks for your answer xbonez.

Comment: I'm sure that would work as well. I personally find it easier to traverse it this way (recursively), than if it were just a list of idents. I'd set up a function `traverIdentList`: `if (identlist.leftnode is identlistnode) { traverseIdentList(leftnode); } else { traverseident(leftnode); } traverseident(rightnode);`

Comment: Good point. I'm going to use that recursive approach for mathematical operators later on.

Comment: I can't decide which answer to accept. They are both helpful XD.

Comment: For mathematical operators, it is imperative you follow this approach. This takes care of operator precedence at parse time.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at how Microsoft is doing this with Roslyn. You could see there how did they declare syntax trees for C# (and VB.NET) and maybe you could even use it instead of parts of your interpreter before you write them.

Specifically, Roslyn syntax tree for your `using` directive looks like this:

```
UsingDirective
    UsingKeyword
    QualifiedName
        IdentifierName (System)
        DotToken
        IdentifierName (Xml)
    SemicolonToken
```

So, similar to your second version, but more detailed.

I think your first version doesn't make much sense. `Xml` is not a child of `System` on the syntactic level (even though you might have a concept of “parent namespace” later on on the semantic level).

Comment: But that's not an abstract syntax tree, it's a concrete syntax tree, as it includes parts of the source code like the dot and semicolon.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But I think you could base your AST on this.